# AS3 monochromatic images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'd like to keep a lot of images as bitmapData in memory. The images are monochromatic, so I actually don't need RGB or RGBA values. Is there any way to set the internal format of a bitmapData to monochromatic or another way to display images other than using BitmapData?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not monochromatic format for BitmapData.

No, you can't display images in anything other them BitmapData (ok, shaders and such, but it's really not the same).

However, you could use ByteArray to save the data not used currently to later use some BitmapData and `setPixel` to set pixels by splitting the single channel value into 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have up to 4 images the same size, you could re-use a single `BitmapData` object to store all of them in different channels, and use a `ColorMatrixFilter` to show just the channel you want.

This would be faster (and *probably* less code) than wvxvw's suggestion of storing the data in a ByteArray and using setPixel.

```
// store data in the red channel
bitmap.bitmapData.copyChannel( im1.bitmapData, im1.bitmapData.rect, new Point(), BitmapDataChannel.RED, BitmapDataChannel.RED );
// store data in the green channel
bitmap.bitmapData.copyChannel( im2.bitmapData, im2.bitmapData.rect, new Point(), BitmapDataChannel.GREEN, BitmapDataChannel.GREEN);

// e.g. filter the bitmap to just show the green channel
// (1's in first col for red, 3rd col for blue, 4th for alpha
var greenChannelFilter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter( 
            [ 0,1,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,255 ]);
bitmap.filters = [greenChannelFilter];
```